# Freeware HTML Editor for Mac similar to Taco HTML Edit

Tags: html, editor, text-editor, html-editor

What is a good, free HTML editor for Mac with features similar to Taco HTML Edit (component library, preview, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextMate is hands down **the best** I've used, but unfortunately it's not free.

The other that comes to mind it TextWrangler, which is a simplified version of the more popular BBEdit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with TextWrangler and preview HTML in Firefox. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Taco HTML Edit is available for mac.  I use BBEdit and TextWrangler is great, although neither is strictly html.  Coda is another option, but also not free.

Comment: I know that Taco HTML is for Mac but I am looking for a similar program for free.